# Microsoft Teams Bot: Starting a new thread with mentioning channel

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

New to Microsoft Teams Botframework, I am able to send a message to the channel, but not able to mention the channel name, 
the samples here talks about mentioning specific user, but not the channel,

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/57.teams-conversation-bot

```
    mention = Mention(
        mentioned=turn_context.activity.from_property,
        text=f"<at>{turn_context.activity.from_property.name}</at>",
        type="mention",
    )

    reply_activity = MessageFactory.text(f"Hello {mention.text}")
    reply_activity.entities = [Mention().deserialize(mention.serialize())]
    await turn_context.send_activity(reply_activity)
```

Not sure how to use the above code to mention the channel name.

Comment: Currently Mention can be done only for user. What is the user case for mentioning the channel?

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT One of the functionality of the bot is a reminder, which reminds the channel every week, and in our organization we have few mandates to be completed, and we use this as a place to followup.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported, but you can suggest it as a feature in the Teams app itself

[image: Suggest a feature]